# Discord bot update message. (Discord.py)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, bots, discord.py

Windows 10
VSCode
Discord.py
Python 3

Hey guys, I want my bot to send a message to a specific channel every time it logs on, here is the code:

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    channel = client.get_channel(788532498724290641)
    await channel.send('I have been updated and am now online again.')
```

There are no errors however no message gets sent when the program is run.

The whole program can be found here but beware it's uncommented and janky: https://github.com/DavisStanko/Discord-Bot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have multiple `on_ready` events. You can only have 1 type of each event, otherwise the last interpreted event will be the only one recognized. Merge the two `on_ready` events into 1 function.

Answer (score -1):

@Kelo This is true, but also the await command must be in a print format, such as

```
    await channel.print ('I am online')
```

I could be wrong, but this is how I have done it in the past with no issues.